# Multiple environment Azure Blob storage connection strings seem to conflict

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Let me start by saying I'm having a hard time wording a query to find answers to this question. I'm not even sure how to describe this in brief for a proper title... Anyway, I've scoured S.O. and various places around the web to get an answer, but am coming up with donuts. So...

I have an API (.NET, C#) that works across three environment branches: `dev`, `qa`, `prod`. 
I have three Azure App Services to support those three environments: `appServDev`, `appServQa`, `appServPod`.
I also have Azure Blob storage for each environment as well: `blobDev`, `blobQa`, `blobProd`; each with a blob storage container to hold some data necessary to sever up to the end user. Additionally, within the production Blob storage I have a blob container that is intended to share a specific set of files across all three program environments, let's call that `mySharedStorage`. This container does not exist in `blobDev` or `blobQa`

So the blob container structure is kind of like this:

```
blobDev
  -myDevStorage

blobQa
  -myQaStorage

blobProd
  -myProdStorage
  -mySharedStorage
```

Where the `my[environment]Storage` blob container has replicated data across all environments, and Dev and Qa just have a smaller subset of the prod data. We have to do this to separate data away from prod for testing. `mySharedStorage` has environment insensitive data that all three need (simply used to download a .pdf file to the user).

In the Registry.cs and the Web.Config I've set up connection strings to access the appropriate storage based on environment. 
In the Web.Config I have these lines where the value will transform based on environment:

```
  <add key="MyAzureConnectionString" value="" />
  <add key="MyAzureSharedConnectionString" value="" />
```

The `MyAzureSharedConnectionString` ends up obtaining the proper connection string for `blobProd > mySharedStorage`, whereas `MyAzureConnectionString` obtains the string for the appropriate environmental connection string (e.g. QA gets `blobQA > myQaStorage` connection string);

However, I cannot get Dev and QA environments to access files in `mySharedStorage`. What seems to happen when I step through the code is the `MyAzureConnectionString` seems to override the environment for the `MyAzureSharedConnectionString`. Basically in Dev and QA the program is looking for `mySharedStorage` container in the wrong environment where it doesn't exist. In prod, however, this all works just fine.. because it exists there!

To test all of this I hardcode the two connection strings where the shared is always the proper production shared storage, and the other I change between the three environments. Dev and QA fail, and Prod always works.

What do I need to do to get Dev and QA to point to the proper shared storage?

EDIT: More info as requested.
This all uses a `BlobStorageUtility` with a the following constructor:

```
public BlobStorageUtility(
  string blobContainerName,
  string storageConnectionString,
  bool isPublic = true)
{
  this._storageConnectionString = storageConnectionString;
  this.SetBlobContainer(blobContainerName, isPublic);
}
```

And in the Registry.cs file:

```
For<IBlobStorageUtility>().Use<BlobStorageUtility>()
    .Named("prodBlobStorageUtility")
    .Ctor<string>("blobContainerName").Is(settings["ProdBlobContainerName"])
    .Ctor<string>("storageConnectionString").Is(settings["AzureStorageConnectionString"])
    .Ctor<bool>("isPublic").Is(true);

For<IBlobStorageUtility>().Use<BlobStorageUtility>()
    .Named("sharedBlobStorageUtility")
    .Ctor<string>("blobContainerName").Is(settings["SharedBlobContainerName"])
    .Ctor<string>("storageConnectionString").Is(settings["AzureSharedStorageConnectionString"])
    .Ctor<bool>("isPublic").Is(true);
```

and Also int the Web.Config to get values for the registry...

```
    <add key="ProdBlobContainerName" value="prodWebSite" />
    <add key="SharedBlobContainerName" value="sharedSite-files" />
```

the production code where the file is being accesed

```
public class SharedFileService : ISharedFileService
{
    private readonly IBlobStorageUtility _blobStorageUtility;
    private readonly IFileDetailService _fileDetailService

    public MsdsService(IFileDetailService fileDetailService, IBlobStorageUtility blobStorageUtility)
    {
        _blobStorageUtility = blobStorageUtility;
        _fileDetailService = fileDetailService;
    }

    ...

    public FileDto GetFile (int? fileId, string fileName)
    {
        var filename = _fileDetailService.GetfileInfo(fileId, fileName).FileName;
        var contentType = GetContentType(filename); //gets the type of file, in this case a pdf

        // This next line is where I can see the blobStorageUtility is pointed to the wrong environment, not shared
        _blobStorageUtility.SetBlobContainer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharedBlobContainerName"]);
        // so then this line fails with a null reference... 
        var blobReference = _blobStorageUtility.GetBlockBlobReference($"{filename}");

        if (blobReference.Exists())
        {
            blobReference.FetchAttributes();

            var byteArr = new byte[blobReference.Properties.Length];
            blobReference.DownloadToByteArray(byteArr, 0);

            return new FileDto() { File = byteArr, ContentType = contentType };
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As a workaround to this issue we just duplicated the shared storage across all three environments with only a small subset of data for testing. This is not ideal and defeats the purpose of the shared storage. However, it accomplishes the task. I would still love to figure out a solution where we can access Prod Shared storage from any environment while maintaining connection to the Dev and QA storage at the same time.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code where you’re reading the settings from web.config file (probably Registry.cs).

Comment: More content added @GauravMantri